ARDL model on monetary policy study on eviews
I am actually writing my master's theses  on monetary policy trnasmission and I am doubting the results of my ARDL approach . I have 4 models ( 1 benchmark and 3 alternatives )
can someone take a look  please ?!!  I would like to know if the results are normal . Also , how do we interpret Boundtest  on ARDL ?
my supervisor said it was okay but he didn't actually read it .

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
